# after getting otp i want to redirect to verify otp page

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.NewActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.aayushchaubey.meetdax.R;
import com.example.activity.HomeActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by DIS015 on 4/18/2018.
 */

public class PhoneNumberRegistration extends AppCompatActivity{

    EditText phoneNo_Edt;
    Button loginBtn;
    TextView incorrectTv,reSendOtpTv;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private static final String TAG = "FirebasePhoneNumAuth";
    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
    String mVerificationId;
    String id,token;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phoneno_login);

        phoneNo_Edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNoEdt);
        incorrectTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.icorrectTv);
        loginBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.phoneNoLoginBtn);
        reSendOtpTv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resendCode);
        phoneNo_Edt.setSingleLine();
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        addOnclickListener();

        mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
                // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
                //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
                // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
                //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
                //     user action.
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);

                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);

                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // Invalid request
                    // ...
                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                    // ...
                }

                // Show a message and update the UI
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;

                // ...
            }
        };


    }

    public void addOnclickListener(){
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendSms();
                }
        });
        reSendOtpTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String phonrNumber=phoneNo_Edt.getText().toString();
                resendVerificationCode(phonrNumber,mResendToken);
            }
        });

        }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            updateUI();
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void updateUI() {
        Toast.makeText(PhoneNumberRegistration.this, "you were logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void sendSms(){
        String phoneNumber=phoneNo_Edt.getText().toString();
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

    }

    private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                        PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
    }


    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();

                            if(mVerificationId!=null){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VerifyOtp.class);
                                intent.putExtra("verificationcode",mVerificationId);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                updateUI();
                            }

                            // ...
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

I am using firebase phone number authentication in my android app.After entering the number i am receiving otp and i want to redirect the page to verify otp page its not working.Also if delete the number in firestore authentication its not sending otp again i don't know what mistake i am doing.I had followed the documentation in firebase console.

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or is this code just "not working"?

Comment: i am not getting error.this code is working only for some phone numbers.i am trying to fix this issue past three days